# Installing local Ruby gem, using bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Our Gemfile is as follows:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'langrove', :path => "/home/user/gems/"
```

The .gem file is in place in "/home/user/gems/ItIsHere.gem"

But when we run *bundle install*, the following error is received:

```
Could not find gem 'ItIsHere (>= 0) ruby' in source at /home/user/gems.
Source does not contain any versions of 'ItIsHere (>= 0) ruby'
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to run `gem unpack`  on the specific .gem you want to use

Then reference the unpacked version.

I normally keep things relative to my project

eg:

```
gem 'awesomelib', :path => '../awesomelib'
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the gem version.For this reason you got error.so you will change the code like this.

```
gem 'remotipart', '1.0.5', :path => "/home/user/gems/"
```

And check your folder :path also.

Answer (score 1):

first

> rails new app_name --skip-bundle

then

use `bundle install --local`
This will install gems from local.